# Create a trigger in Postgres that will insert a record to another table with added column

Tags: postgresql

I have these 2 tables created in postgres,

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
   ID           INT             PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   NAME         VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS      VARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE HIST_EMPLOYEE(
   HISTORYNUM   INT             NOT NULL,
   ID           INT             NOT NULL,
   NAME         VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS      VARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL
);
```

..so whenever I want to insert, update, or delete a record in my `EMPLOYEE` table, that record should be inserted in `HIST_EMPLOYEE` table. regardless if it is single or multiple rows

..I know that there are lots of answers in this site..but the problem is I added a column in my HISTORY table `HIST_EMPLOYEE`..that's why I cant used this script that most of the answers posted,

```
insert into hist_employee select * from employee
```

...this is what i've started so far, but it has so many errors..

***TRIGGER***

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertHistory
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON employee   --MAIN TABLE
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertHistory('hist_employee');  --HISTORY TABLE
```

***TRIGGER FUNCTION***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertHistory() RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$func$
    BEGIN
       EXECUTE format('insert into %I select * from %I', TG_ARGV[0] ,TG_TABLE_NAME );
       return null;
    END;
$func$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

> NOTE:
>
> 1. This trigger should be also applicable or flexible enough to be implemented on other tables with different set of columns.
> 2. HISTORYNUM column is unique per id,
> 3. And, is it possible to combine these 3, **AFTER INSERT, AFTER UPDATE, BEFORE DELETE** .. in one trigger ??

thanks to all who will respond..sorry if you find my question too vague

Comment: Is HISTORYNUM and employee(id) able to be serials?

Comment: HISTORYNUM field should have a default value